# Actions after PromptDialog.Choice

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

This shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm new to C# and can't seem to fix it. I have a Prompt.Dialog.Choice to confirm a message if the user want the inputs to be sent to a database or not.

I'm stuck in the ChoiceReceivedAsync where I want to make actions weather or not the user answers "yes" or "no", but how do I call these answers in my if-else sentence?

Here's the relevant code:

```
public enum booleanChoice { Yes, No }

public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        //var message = await result as IMessageActivity;
        await context.PostAsync("Do you want you message to be sent?");

        PromptDialog.Choice(
            context: context,
            resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
            options: (IEnumerable<booleanChoice>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(booleanChoice)),
            prompt: " ",
            retry: "Please try again.",
            promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto
        );
    }

public async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<booleanChoice> result)
    {
        booleanChoice response = await result;

        //Here's where I'm stuck:
        //if (PromptDialog.Choice == "Yes"){//send the inputs to the databse}
        //else (PromptDialog.Choice == "No"){//exit or enter the message again}


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to compare your result (`response`) to your enum values, like the following:

```
public async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<booleanChoice> result)
{
    booleanChoice response = await result;

    if (response.Equals(booleanChoice.Yes))
    {
        //send the inputs to the databse}
    else 
    {
        //exit or enter the message again
    }
}
```